# Hopkins statistic - to exponentiate or not to exponentiate?

Tags: r, clustering

I wanted to cluster https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/iabhishekofficial/mobile-price-classification?resource=download data.

I used 2 different R implementations of Hopkins statistic:

hopkins::hopkins() (https://github.com/kwstat/hopkins/blob/main/R/hopkins.R) and

factoextra::get_clust_tendency() (https://github.com/kassambara/factoextra/blob/master/R/get_clust_tendency.R)

Both functions returned vastly different results (~.98 vs ~ .55). It seems that the difference is due to hopkins() exponentiating the final sums of distances as such:

```
return( sum(dux^d) / sum( dux^d + dwx^d ) )
```

while get_clust_tendency() does not perform this operation:

```
list(hopkins_stat = sum(minp)/(sum(minp) + sum(minq)), plot = plot)
```

I have seen both versions of the definition e.g. 1) https://www.datanovia.com/en/lessons/assessing-clustering-tendency/ after https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ci00065a010 or 2) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopkins_statistic,  https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1375706. This seems to be a big problem so I would like to ask an expert to weigh in.

Comment: According to the original paper and some reviews, IIRC, exponentiation of the terms in the formula is necessary

Comment: `due to hopkins() exponentiating the final sums of distances` Not the sums but the distances themselves.

Answer (score 1):

The `factoextra` package calculates Hopkins Statistic in the same way as the `clustertend` package, which has now been deprecated.  I believe the `hopkins` package gives a better answer.  If you want to know why, have a look at this paper: "Will the Real Hopkins Statistic Please Stand Up?", https://journal.r-project.org/articles/RJ-2022-055/

FYI, I am author of the `hopkins` package.

Comment: Very interesting article. I've been writing the Hopkins stat. macro for SPSS. And was doing simulations to check its distribution. Kevin, is there a way to email you if I need to communicate and discuss the topic?

Comment: Sure.  Use `packageDescription("hopkins")` to get the contact info for a package.

Comment: Thank you, Kevin! When I come back to work on my hopkins project I will email you.